# Add a Gem Path?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

When I run `gem environment` I get a list which includes the following:

> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /home/rescue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
>   - /home/rescue/.gem/ruby/2.3.0

I'd like to add a path. I see people [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323310/773263) to add something like `export GEM_PATH = ...` to my `.bashrc` file, but I fear this would replace the existing gem paths.

How can I add another path in addition to the ones that already exist?

Comment: https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install

Answer (score 2):

When you run `echo $GEM_PATH` you'll probably see 2 paths separated with colon. It's standard in setting multiple paths in env variables.

If you want to add more directories then you can add 1 more path without removing old ones with `EXPORT GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:/your/new/path`

Comment: When I `echo $GEM_PATH` I get back a blank line, despite seeing multiple entries in `gem environment`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to just add path without override.

Answer your question is in

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems.rb#L404

```
 when 'GEM_HOME', 'GEM_PATH', 'GEM_SPEC_CACHE'
 .... 
 @paths = Gem::PathSupport.new ENV.to_hash.merge(target)
```

Code is complicated, but you can read  that you can set path only by one of these `'GEM_HOME', 'GEM_PATH', 'GEM_SPEC_CACHE'` variables.

Then gem put these variables as constructor to `Gem::PathSupport` where paths are set.

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/path_support.rb

Answer (score 1):

`GEM_PATH=XXXX:`

(NOTE: should ends with a colon)

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/dc86a62ac36f9cb4dea9de93fb9d8f791ef2f08a/lib/rubygems/path_support.rb#L55