# Permission denied, when installing a new gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am in Windows 7, I can see that all my gems are in :
C:\Users\alotfi2.gem\specs\api.rubygems.org%443\quick\Marshal.4.8

Last week we received an email from the admin that said :

After migration, your H: drive will be read-only. This means you'll be able to access and transfer your files but you won't be able to edit them or save any new files to your H: drive.

but when I tried to install a new gem I got :

gem install chronic
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - H:/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/chronic-0.10.2.gemspec

```
gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.3.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.2 (2017-09-14 patchlevel 198) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: H:/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - H:/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\majid\cmder\bin
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoes
     - C:\Ruby24-x64\bin
     - C:\Users\alotfi2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\
     - C:\Users\alotfi2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
     - C:\Users\alotfi2\AppData\Roaming\npm
     - C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin
     - C:\majid\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\share\vim\vim74
     - C:\majid\cmder\
```

your help is appreciated .
Thanks.

Comment: SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY still links to your H drive. Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303180/rubygems-how-to-change-gem-environment-settings) thread.

Comment: How to do these in windows :    export GEM_PATH=/Users/myusername/Tools/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
export GEM_SPEC_CACHE=/Users/myusername/Tools/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/specs

Comment: @Majid https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+set+environment+variable

Comment: @Tom Lord, I have already added C:\Users\alotfi2\.gem\specs to PATH in windows, but  still get :   GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - H:/.gem/ruby/2.4.0

Comment: What do you mean? That link says you need to update the gem specs cache, not the gem path.

Comment: And this has got nothing to do with updating your PATH.

Comment: How  to update the gem specs cache in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY still links to your H: drive, to change its value, you have to set environment variable GEM_SPEC_CACHE as stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303180/rubygems-how-to-change-gem-environment-settings).
To do so on Windows, you would want to use [SetX](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command. For example:

```
SETX GEM_SPEC_CACHE C:\Users\User\.gem\abc
```

You should have writing access rights to directory C:\Users\User\.gem\abc for it to work.